# Static Injector Error showing up instead of loading page

Tags: angular

I'm new one for the Angular. I defined all of the components correctly. But when I set routes to redirect from one page to another This error will showing up [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6wrL.jpg).

I already added HttpsClientModule in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import{HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';
import { ReservationComponent } from './reservation/reservation.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: EmployeeComponent},
  {path:'reservation', component: ReservationComponent},

];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeComponent,
    ReservationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [], 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this. As I'm a new one for angular anyone please help me!

Comment: as the error states, add "ReservationService" in "providers" of the AppModule

Comment: Thanks for answering my noob question. I highly appreciate your kind helpfullness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the *ReservationService* into your *app.module.ts* file and also add it to the *providers* array.

Answer (score 0):

As Florian said, add ReservationService  to providers of AppModule .

Update app module to this one

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import{HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';
import { ReservationComponent } from './reservation/reservation.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: EmployeeComponent},
  {path:'reservation', component: ReservationComponent},

];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeComponent,
    ReservationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [ReservationService], 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```